# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary Error while writing to Parquet File

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

When I am trying to write the data to Parquet file I am facing below mentioned error. I read post about if two Parquet files have different datatypes then we will see this error. But I tried individually casting all the columns in the dataframe also I am trying to write to a new directory that doesn't have any files.

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 787 in stage 76.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 787.3 in stage 76.0 (TID 77007) (100.100.191.241 executor 145): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainIntegerDictionary
    at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToBinary(Dictionary.java:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToBinary(ParquetDictionary.java:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.WritableColumnVector.getUTF8String(WritableColumnVector.java:400)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:79)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you are trying to write values to the Parquet file?